# Debug mysteriously disappearing files from file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, fileserver

We've been having an issue in our production system lately where some files have been disappearing, or their names changed which breaks the reference to them in the database.

I've added logs to places where I suspect the bug might be, but the codebase is large and there are many flows where files are deleted/copied/moved, so it's difficult to find the problem like this.

My question is whether it's possible to somehow extend the File Delete/CopyTo/MoveTo methods from .NET in order to catch every file operation, and log it, along with the StackTrace to know where the request came from?

If not, then I'd appreciate some tips on how to tackle this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This one is going to be pretty hard for you to capture.  You have FileSystemWatcher that you could use to at least capture and bring the file back if it is that critical.  But it doesn't give you any context information on how/what made the change, just that a change happened.

The same even goes for shell hooks, which you wouldn't want to do either. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144063(v=vs.85).aspx)

As for hooking into all calls to the File classes, if would be possible if you had a wrapping class, but otherwise it is going to be hard.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ionad.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Ionad). It allows to replace static method calls on whole assembly.

```
PM> Install-Package Ionad.Fody
```

But it replaces methods completely, so you can't use original functionality by default.
To extend the methods you have to create wrappers in separate project / assembly.

For example. Add new project to your solution. Do NOT apply Fody.Ionad to it. Add wrappers for all of the methods you need to extend:

```
public static class FileHelper
{
    public static void Delete(string path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        File.Delete(path);
    }
}
```

Apply Fody.Ionad to your main project where you need to replace methods and add substitutes with `StaticReplacement` attribute:

```
[StaticReplacement(typeof(File))]
public static class FileSubstitute
{
    public static void Delete(string path)
    {
        FileHelper.Delete(path);
    }
}
```

Now when you call `File.Delete("path")` it will output the path to console and delete the file.

If you using some framework that hides `File` calls in own methods, you have to apply Fody.Ionad add substitutes to that framework too.